# jQuery equivalent of MooTools' Scroll().toElementCenter()

Tags: jquery, mootools

I am adapting someone else's script to my site. The use MooTools; I use jQuery. Their code has the following line:

```
new FX.Scroll(window).toElementCenter('obj');
```

How would I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [check the docs](http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.6.0/Fx/Fx.Scroll#Fx-Scroll:toElementCenter) you see this line

```
new FX.Scroll(window).toElementCenter('obj');
```

means basically:

> Do a animated scroll to the center of the element with the id "`obj`"

And in jQuery that can be done with

```
var obj = $('#obj'); // cache the element
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: obj.offset() + (obj.height() / 2) // scroll to top of element + half of its height
}, 1000); // 1 second fast animation
```